# Implementing a tick/round based combat system

Tags: c#, xna

i like to get some thoughts on how to implement a tick based system.

Every action a player or non player got has a initial time to perform and a cooldown time. Once a creatures cooldown time has passed it gets to choose a new action. If the player has to choose a action the game is "paused".

Example:

1: Player heavy swing (50 ticks to perform, 50 ticks to cool down)

2: Game goes on for 50 ticks.

3: NPC's can set actions.

4: Player swings and cools down for 50 ticks.

5: NPC's can set actions.

6: Game paused for the player.

What i currently have works but is not efficient. I have a class with each action as a static method. These method output a struct containing all the data. This will be passed to a actioncue of a individual creature.

Every update loop call the cue and start counting down the attack time if the player has put in a action. Once the attack should be solved i call a static method in the actions class again. And i start counting down the cooldown timer.

So what i should have is probably a list holding all actions and sorting that list skipping unnecessary time/ticks and go straight to the next action. But there will be different types of actions like move, attack, ability and i cant wrap my head around a good implementation of this.

When a creature performs a basic attack this gets called (attack is the creatures own instanced attack struct)

```
attack = Actions.BasicAttack(this, player, rand);
```

This is how the Actions class looks like.

```
public struct Attack
    {
        public int Damage;
        public string Type;
        public int Time;
        public int Cooldown;
        public Creature target;
        public bool solved;
    }




    public static Attack BasicAttack(Creature attacker, Creature defender, Random rand)
    {
        Attack attack = new Attack();

        attack.Damage = rand.Next(attacker.MinBaseDmg, attacker.MaxBaseDmg + 1);
        attack.Type = "Melee";
        attack.Time = 50;
        attack.Cooldown = 30;
        attack.target = defender;
        attack.solved = false;

        return attack;
    }
```

And this gets called in the update method of each creature when the player has a action cued. Tick = 0 if player has no action cued and tick = 1 when player has a action cued up.

```
protected void ActionCue(int tick)
    {
        if (attack.target != null)
        {
            if (attack.Time > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(attack.Time);
                attack.Time -= tick;
                this.free = false;
            }
            else if (!attack.solved)
            {
                Actions.SolveAttack(attack.Damage, attack.Type, attack.target);
                attack.solved = true;
            }
            else if (attack.solved && attack.Cooldown > 1)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(attack.Cooldown);
                attack.Cooldown -= tick;
            }
            else
                free = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: paste in the code. Deducing what you are doing from a description that doesnt even use actual classnames is a pain

Comment: I most probably need a whole different way of doing it. But i try to paste in some code to let you guys see what i currently have.

Comment: I am also running into problems when i need different kinds of actions like moving. I need a way to make things more flexible get cued up and directly calculating which action is next to perform.

Comment: @MennoGouw - So create a base movement class and inherit it.  Your question is not clear.  It seems clear you are not far enough in the project for us to help you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You said the current system works.

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean? I have everything working it just is very slow since it uses the update function to count down. I need some opinions on how someone else would approach a task like this.

Currently i am making a Ability class which that can create all the things a creature can do, how much time it takes, etc.

When a ability is called it the creature gets a active flag and the ability should be placed in a list and have a function tell which ability should perform first. Once the cooldown is over a creature gets the unactive flag and can perform again.

Hope this is going to work.

Comment: @JustinSkiles Yeah but it is very slow since each update method it is counting down. Its even slow for just the player and one other creature. Now it takes as long as the (time for each update * ticks till ability performing) + (time update * cooldown).

It is just not very well programmed.

Comment: Basically what i am asking has nothing to do with my code (but someone asked for it). I am only looking for some thoughts and opinions on a structure to make a tick based system i described.

Comment: The thing is, Stackoverflow isn't really the place to have a discussion of thoughts and opinions. Questions should be to the point with a specific problem and solution. Anything else needs to go to the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Problem = tick based system.
Question = A structure on how to implement such a system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider something like this (i will use pseudocode - its far from being optimized etc. but it might be just fast enough, or set you on your way to optimize what youre trying to do)

```
class CombatEventList
{
   public static AddEvent(CombatEvent event, int ticksTillHappens)   
}

virtual class CombatEvent
{
    public virtual void CombatAction()
}

class PlayerActionChoice : ComabtEvent
{
   public void CombatAction
   {
       var playerAction = GetUserDecision();//returns i.e CombatEvent PlayerMeeleAttack
       CombatEventList.AddEvent(playerAction, 0);
   }
}

class PlayerMeeleAttack : CombatEvent
{
   int cooldownInTicks = 50;

   public void CombatAction
   {
       MakeAttack()//damages the moster etc - all the stuff the attack is supposed to do
       var nextEvent = new PlayerActionChoice();
       CombatEventList.AddEvent(nextEvent, cooldownInTicks);
   }
}
```

So, how this works?

We got a list of events.

The list checks all the events that are supposed to happen now and, executes their CombatAction.

In their CombatAction, the events add new events to the list. For example a PlayerMeeleAttack event sets the PlayerActionChoice event after an appropriate cooldown, so that he can take another action later.

After all current CombatEvents are resolved and have added their own CombatEvents to the list, the list checks the next Event (lowest delay)

The list sleeps for the specified number of ticks (the delay of the next Event). Once its done sleeping, it lowers the cooldowns on all events by an appropriate amount, and handles all  the current events (those that just hit 0 delay)

This goes in a loop

The list starts with the CombatStartEvent on it, thats going to happen right away(delay 0). It sets the PlayerActionChoice and MonsterActionChoice events in the CombatAction method.

Of course this is far from being optimal, its just a sketch, or an idea for you to think through. There may be better ideas, i didnt give the problem very much thought - but this is obviously more efficient than your current solution :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, i am well away on my new approach but it seems a lot messier then your code. Never got into events yet so this is a good time to do that. This looks very clear, thank you!

Comment: Just for clarity - im using classes named as Events, but they are not actually events (language structure). This might be a bit missleading - sorry for that. Of course, you could implement this using actual events! But this isnt necessary ;)

Comment: Yeah i get that, i know the difference between a name of a class/method and a actual event but thanks for clarifying :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a couple of hours it seems i got this working. Here is the code for anyone who needs it. I am open for feedback too.

This is the ability class, everything needed can be added here. For the tick based system just the time variables are important.

```
public string AbilityName { get; private set; }
    public int minDamage { get; private set; }
    public int maxDamage { get; private set; }

    public int ActivationTime { get; private set; }
    public int CooldownTime { get; private set; }
    public int Timer;

    public Ability(string AbilityName)
    {
        if (AbilityName == "attack")
        {
            this.AbilityName = AbilityName;
            minDamage = 10;
            maxDamage = 20;
            ActivationTime = 20;
            CooldownTime = 30;
            Timer = ActivationTime;

            iconPath = "ability/icon/attack";
        }
    }
```

This is the task class, the ability, attacker and targets get passed as parameters, a ability name or type can be used to perform different kinds/types of abilities such as movement vs attacking.

```
public Ability ability { get; private set; }
    public bool onCooldown;

    public Creature attacker { get; private set; }
    List<Creature> targets = new List<Creature>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initiates a attack task
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="attacker"></param>
    /// <param name="defender"></param>
    public Task(Creature attacker, List<Creature> targets, Ability ability)
    {
        this.ability = ability;
        this.attacker = attacker;
        this.targets = targets;

        onCooldown = false;
    }

    public void Perform()
    {
        //performce abilty
        Console.WriteLine(attacker.Name + " performce ability");
    }
```

The player or AI can now create a task from the abilities they own like so:

```
targets.Add(player); //This is just a basic attack so only one "creature" gets in the list
                task = new Task(this, targets, abilityList[0]); //Task is created
                taskList.Add(task); //Task is added to a list i manage in a main class
                free = false; //creature is put on hold and cant do anything till task is completed
```

This is where most of the magic happens. In the main class this method is being called each update if the player is not "free". I update all the tasks before i do anything with the task next in line because i dont want to edit its stats after updating its status.

```
private void TaskHandler()
    {
        int ticksToAdvance = 0;
        // get the next task requiring a action
        taskList.Sort((x, y) => x.ability.Timer.CompareTo(y.ability.Timer));

        //get the amount of cooldown left
        ticksToAdvance = taskList[0].ability.Timer;

        //Update all tasks
        foreach (Task t in taskList)
        {
            t.ability.Timer -= ticksToAdvance;
        }

        //check if this task is on cooldown
        if (taskList[0].onCooldown)
        {
            //Reset ability timer, free creature and remove task from the list.
            taskList[0].ability.Timer = taskList[0].ability.ActivationTime;
            taskList[0].attacker.free = true;
            taskList.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        else
        {
            //perform ability
            taskList[0].Perform();
            //set timer to cooldown
            taskList[0].onCooldown = true;
            taskList[0].ability.Timer = taskList[0].ability.CooldownTime;
        }
    }
```